# MySQL ram usages on default pod

Tags: mysql, docker, memory, kubernetes

Im trying to run a basic MySQL 8 pod in Kubernetes. I did a basic deployment without any resource limits or whatsoever. What i do notice that the memory consumption is high. I have a nearly empty database (i think there are max 100 rows with basic data) and the pod is consuming 750M memory.

Is there anything that you can do about this?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: mysql:8.0
          resources:
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: mydb
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: myuser
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret
                  key: "DATABASE_PASSWORD"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: transport
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              subPath: mysql
      volumes:
        - name: db
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db
```

Best 
Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did to reduce the consumption mainly is disable the performance schema. Further i reduced the default connection limit to ensure that it does not reserve the memory for those who are not being used.

It will indeed mean that it can collapse if there are more users but i guess its a guess in on one of those

- more cluster ram or failing to run it due to ram exhaustion
- hit the max connection limit

Proper monitoring on all will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I've just ran a docker container with MySQL and it consumes ~400M of RAM with an empty database that is not even being queried by some application.

```
docker run -itd -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql
docker stats
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
a779ef705921        happy_lumiere       2.22%               373.4MiB / 1.943GiB   18.77%              1.05kB / 0B         0B / 0B             38
```

According to this assessment it seems to me that 750M is not that much.

You can check out these [Best Practices for Configuring Optimal MySQL Memory Usage](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/03/best-practices-for-configuring-optimal-mysql-memory-usage/).

Comment: i see that mainly the performance_schema is the once consuming much memory. Is it normal to keep it active? While disabling it drops from 700M to 200M

Comment: As far as I know the performance schema is used for monitoring so the decision depends on whether you need the monitoring data or not. I am not a MySQL DBA though so I may be wrong.

Comment: regarding performance schema's use, @vkozyrev is right, its totally optional. There's even a reasonable amount of stats monitoring without it. Seems like a good thing to cut out.

Answer (score 1):

In the future please add more information about your environment (local, `kubeadm`, `minikube`, `cloud`) and scenario. It would be easier to reproduce or troubleshoot.

I would not say that `750M` RAM is high consumption. For test I've deployed `MySQL 8.0` on my GKE cluster using `HELM` based on [this chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mysql). I've only changed default MySql image version to `8.0`.

`$ helm install sql stable/mysql`

Pure instance of MySQL on my cluster without any `limits`, `requests` or data:

```
$ kubectl top pods
NAME                         CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
sql-mysql-6c9489d5b9-m8zmh   8m           376Mi
```

So if `MySQL` works with actual data it's normal to consume more resources.

I would say it's normal behaviour.

For general resources use in `MySql` you can check [How MySQL Uses Memory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-use.html).

However if you working on local environment with some limited resources you should specify [Limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) in your YAMLs.